# TypeScript property not found error:

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am getting the below error in my vscode:

```
[ts] Property 'getPatientAllAddress' does not exist on type 'Object'.
```

Why does it check for getPatientAllAddress() method which is getting added dynamically? 
This usually does not happen in `Javascript`.

```
get addresses() {
    if (this.data && this.data.hasOwnProperty("getPatientAllAddress")) {
        return this.data.getPatientAllAddress();
    }
}
```

How to supress/ignore this warning.

Comment: as far as I know you have to declare a "data type" of this.data, either through an interface or inline where you are declaring `data`. What typescript is telling you is that you have declared `data` as a regular Object, but he has no clue whether the property "getPatientAllAddress" effectively exists and is a function: to assert that you have to implement an interface, which will also help you with the intellisense when you type "this.data". If you want to do that inline, something like: `private data: {getPatientAllAddress: ()};` should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Up to this point `this.data` has had type `Object`. The error occurs because you're trying to access a `.getPatientAllAddress()` property on a variable of type `Object`. Even though you've confirmed logically that it should have that property, the compiler isn't yet smart enough to understand it should make that property available on that variable's interface.

**Solution 1**

If you don't have the `noImplicitAny` flag turned on you should be able to get away with changing the last line to

```
return data['getPatientAllAddress']();
```

**Solution 2**

Set the type of `this.data` to `:{getPatientAllAddress?:Function}` (or in a better world create the interface corresponding to this.data which includes that function).

using either Function or the appropriate more specific type.

**Solution 3**

Define an interface for the full data

```
interface Bleh {
    getPatientAllAddress : Function
}
```

and a type guard

```
function isBleh(x:any) : x is Bleh {
    return x && x.hasOwnProperty("getPatientAllAddress");
}
```

and use as

```
if (isBleh(this.data)) {
    this.data.getPatientAllAddress();
}
```

---

Solution 1 is the simplest, Solution 2 is the most correct (though you should really also define everything else in that interface too, not just this optional function), and Solution 3 is halfway me showing off language features and halfway talking about what you'll need to do in situations where 1 and 2 aren't viable.

Comment: For the intellisense completion I would recommend solution 2 though, so that if you will ever need to mantain such a code the intellisense will help you a bit :).

Comment: `getPatientAllAddress: Function` -- I think the `(...args: any[]) => any` type would be better in this situation, which can then be further tightened to the correct parameter list and return type. I would only use `Function` for when an arbitrary function object is used (such as when expecting a class as an argument), and definitely not for a callable interface method.

Comment: @JohnWeisz I agree, but I'm not sure which is clearer for new folks.

Comment: how setting noimplicitany to false solves the problem?

Comment: @Shane it doesn't solve your problem itself. I was explaining that solution 1 only works if you have that flag off. Otherwise it throws an error (`error TS7017: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'Object' has no index signature.`)

Comment: @Shane Accessing properties through brackets, such as `data['getPatientAllAddress']`, uses an index-signature to provide type-safety, which is defined on interfaces as `{ [key: K]: V }` -- for example, a string array has the following index signature: `{ [key: number]: string }`. If you don't explicitly define an index signature, it will have an _implicit_ `{ [key: any]: any }` type, and TypeScript will not allow that with the `noImplicitAny` flag enabled (with this flag you need to give every variable/property/symbol a type).